# Add multiple domains for the same website in google webmasters

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have 3 domains
these 2
http://www.janhendrikx.be
http://www.standenbouw-jan.be
redirect to
http://www.ontwerpbureaujan.be/

In google webmasters I added ontwerpbureaujan
Do I have to add the others too? Or do I get duplicate content
Do I have to use canonical URLs? How?

'Standenbouw' is my main seo keyword, maybe I should add http://www.standenbouw-jan.be to webmasters, not ontwerpbureaujan ? ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure janhendrikx.be & standenbouw-jan.be have 301 redirects to ontwerpbureaujan.be
If not, please get it done by your Web host else Google will actually consider them as three different websites and will crawl them all.

If they have 301 redirects, then you could add the others too and Google would know that they are the same site and hence wouldn't crawl all of them.
But you could still add all of them and it may increase your pagerank for the keyword and in that case you could mention http://www.ontwerpbureaujan.be/ as your preferred domain on the site settings area.

Here are a few recommendations by Google itself:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#4

Good luck!